# Advanced Popover Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with several popovers that are acting as additional information for products.

When functioning as intended a user should be able to click on a popover, and when they click on another popover the previous popover closes. This functionality already exists in my current code, however, when a user does this the previous popover's button does not have its toggle state reset. This means when the user clicks on the second popover and tries clicking on the original one they have to click twice (once to set the toggle back to original state, and once to reopen it).

I would like to know how to reset the toggle state of all other popovers when a new popover is opened.

You can see my current working code here:
http://codepen.io/kcarskadon/pen/BLJdkJ?editors=1010

Here is the current jquery I am using:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: 'true'
    })
    $(document).on("click", ".popover .close" , function(){
        $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
   });
    $(document).on('show.bs.popover', function(){
        $('.popover').not(this).hide()
   });
    $(document).on('hidden.bs.popover', function (e) {
        $(e.target).data("bs.popover").inState.click = false;
   });
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're hiding the item, not using the popover hide function, try it like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: 'true'
    })
    $(document).on("click", ".popover .close" , function(){
        $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
   });
    $(document).on('show.bs.popover', function(){
        $('.popover').not(this).popover('hide');
   });
    $(document).on('hidden.bs.popover', function (e) {
        $(e.target).data("bs.popover").inState.click = false;
   });
});
```

Comment: dont forget to rate ;p